# Removing html code from text data in Spark

Tags: pyspark, nlp, text-processing

i'm working with Stack Exchange data dumps and I want to clean body of a question from code which occurs really often.

I tried using BeautifulSoup but it leaves the text which occurs inside the code and I want to remove everything between  < pre >< code>  and < /code > < /pre >. Maybe it can be done with regular expressions? Preferably with Spark.

Comment: It will be better if you could share a sample of your input data and the corresponding output you're expecting.

Comment: I gave an answer but now that I reread your question I think I misread it, so you want to just strip out anything between the code blocks and return it without the code? for example `a text < pre >< code> some code stuff < /code > < /pre > b text` becomes `a text < pre >< code>< /code > < /pre > b text` or do you want to remove everything so it becomes something like`a text  b text`

Comment: @KenMyers option number 2. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work

```py
# re example
import re
s1 = "< pre >< code> some sample code < /code > < /pre >."
p = re.compile(r"< pre >< code>(.*?)< /code > < /pre >")
print(p.search(s1).group(1))

# convert to UDF
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
codeFinder = udf(lambda x: p.search(x).group(1), returnType=StringType())
df = df.withColumn('codeText', codeFinder(col('htmlCol')))
```

If I misunderstood your question and you wanted to strip out the code blocks then something like this might work

```py
# re example
import re
s2 = "a text <pre><code> some sample code </code></pre> b text"
s3 = "a text <pre><code> some sample code </code></pre> b text <pre><code> some sample code </code></pre> c text"
s4 = """Here is the sample of the post data: But if I open it using MNE it the first list is eeg data, and the second list (inside the list of eeg data) are two list of eeg data.</p>\n\n<p>this is how I open the data using MNE</p>\n\n<pre><code>raw_file=read_raw_edf("E:\eegDATA\\256\s02_reduced.bdf",preload=True,verbose=True)\n</code></pre>\n\n<p>Am I missing something here?</p>\n"""
pattern = r"(?s)<pre><code>(.*?)</code></pre>"
print(re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=s2))  # a text  b text
print(re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=s3))  # a text  b text  c text
print(re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=s4))  


# UDF example
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType, FloatType
codeStripper = udf(lambda x: re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=x), returnType=StringType())
testSchema = StructType([
  StructField("html",StringType(),False),
])
df = spark.createDataFrame([{'html':s3}, {'html':s4}], testSchema)
df = df.withColumn('codelessText', codeStripper(col('html')))
df.toPandas()
```

Comment: Ok, so it actually worked for your simple example, but when i am trying to apply this solution to the real post data, it doesnt change anything. Here is the sample of the post data: " But if I open it using MNE it the first list is eeg data, and the second list (inside the list of eeg data) are two list of eeg data.</p>\n\n<p>this is how I open the data using MNE</p>\n\n<pre><code>raw_file=read_raw_edf("E:\eegDATA\\256\s02_reduced.bdf",preload=True,verbose=True)\n</code></pre>\n\n<p>Am I missing something here?</p>\n  "

Do you have any idea why it didnt work?

Comment: I want to remove all code snippets to be clear, just leave raw text which is OUTSIDE the code snippets.

Comment: It didn't match because the pattern is different than the one you gave earlier. I can rewrite it so that it can account for optional spaces but do you know if there are always "no spaces" or is it possible to have spaces like the earlier example?

Comment: do you mean spaces inside < code > chunk for example? if so, there are always "no spaces" (it looks like this: <pre><code> and </pre></code> ) but i modified your patter deleting these spaces. I wrote it like this because formatting was enabled automatically when i was writing the question. It didint match anyway.

Comment: I updated my answer for you, it should work now